# Transposing a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What would be a good way to efficiently transform a data.table after the data computation is over

```
nrow=500e3
ncol=2000
m <- matrix(rnorm(nrow*ncol),nrow=nrow)
colnames(m) <- c('foo',seq(ncol-1))
dt <- data.table(m)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
dt <- t(dt)  #take a long time and converts the data table to a matrix
```

**compute time**

```
1. to transpose the matrix
system.time(mt <- t(m))
   user  system elapsed
 20.005   0.016  20.024

2. to transpose the dt
system.time(dt <- t(dt))
user  system elapsed
32.722  15.129  47.855

3. to transpose a df
system.time(df <- t(df))
user  system elapsed
32.414  15.357  47.775
```

Comment: `dt[,`10`]` should answer your second question.

Comment: In the second case, use back ticks to quote the column name - as far as R is concerned it is not syntactically valid, but `data.table` will allow you to use anything for a column name. `dt[,list(\`10\`)]`

Comment: I just realized that dt[,'10',with=F] works.. and actually took out the second question

Comment: How long does it take to take the transpose from a `data.frame`? And how much memory do you have on your system? The matrix alone will take 7.4GB in space.

Comment: You're asking us to run `rnorm(1e9)` - that takes several minutes alone if it doesn't make too large a vector first.

Comment: `as.matrix(dt)` is 2x faster than `t(dt)` on my machine.

Comment: @SeñorO, that's not much a surprise I'd suppose. In the first case, the elements are all in the same order (column-wise). But in the 2nd case, each of the row has to be put as a column (and the representation being col-wise, they'd not be in contiguous memory location, cannot `memcpy`).. and you've to do this 5e5 times! At least this is what I think is happening.

Comment: transposing a `data.table` seems like a very strange operation to want to do - can you explain the use case - i.e. in what scenario would you want to convert the matrix to a data.table and then want to go back?

Comment: the down stream code I have is third party and accepts a matrix in a format which is a transpose of the dt. If I was writing my own I would not do a transpose :) ..

Comment: Okay, I'll ask again. How long does it take to transpose from a `data.frame`? And how much memory do you have on your system, because the matrix alone will take 7.4GB space?

Comment: Arun : Sorry I missed your question earlier. I have not tried creating a df and transpose it on this data. For memory I am running this on a 200+Gb machine so that hopefully should not be a problem. Also the eg. is contrived but in similar dimension to real data.

Comment: It'd be nice to know if `data.table` is slow or the operation itself can't be helped. I've tried to give some reasoning as a reply to Senor's post above. So, if you can get the timings for both, then there's something to compare.

Comment: I have updated the OP with the compute times.

Comment: I'd suspect the difference (47-20) is the time taken to get a matrix from DF/DT... I don't think anything can be done here.

Comment: fair enough..I guess it was worth a quick check with you guys.. appreciate all your input. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question, and since then `data.table` has added/exported `transpose` for transposing lists. Performance-wise, it out-performs `t` except on matrices (I think this is to be expected)

```
system.time(t(m))
 #   user  system elapsed 
 # 23.990  23.416  85.722 
system.time(t(dt))
 #   user  system elapsed 
 # 31.223  53.197 195.221 
system.time(t(df))
 #   user  system elapsed 
 # 30.609  45.404 148.323 
system.time(setDT(transpose(dt)))
 #   user  system elapsed 
 # 42.135  38.478 116.599
```