# Compute with data.table: how many 2x2 non NA values there are among the variables?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have this data.table (actual data is 25061 x 5862):

```
require(data.table)
df
  # gene     P1     P2     P3     P4     P5
 # 1: gene1  0.111  0.319  0.151     NA -0.397
 # 2: gene10  1.627  2.252  1.462 -1.339 -0.644
 # 3: gene2 -1.766 -0.056 -0.369  1.910  0.981
 # 4: gene3 -1.346  1.283  0.322 -0.465  0.403
 # 5: gene4 -0.783     NA -0.005  1.761  0.066
 # 6: gene5  0.386 -0.309 -0.886 -0.072  0.161
 # 7: gene6  0.547 -0.144 -0.725 -0.133  1.059
 # 8: gene7  0.785 -1.827  0.986  1.555 -0.798
 # 9: gene8 -0.186     NA  0.401  0.900 -1.075
# 10: gene9 -0.177  1.497 -1.370 -1.628 -1.044
```

I'd like to know how, making advantage of the data.table structure, I can efficiently compute, for each pair of gene values, how many couples there are with no NA. For example, for the pair gene1, gene2, I'd like the result to be 4.

With base R, I do it this way:

```
calc_nonNA <- !is.na(df[, -1, with=F])
Effectifs <- calc_nonNA %*% t(calc_nonNA)
# or, as suggested by @DavidArenburg and @Khashaa, more efficiently:
Effectifs <- tcrossprod(calc_nonNA)
```

But, with a large df, it takes hours...

***My desired output, with the provided example is this:***

```
       gene1 gene10 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5 gene6 gene7 gene8 gene9
gene1      4      4     4     4     3     4     4     4     3     4
gene10     4      5     5     5     4     5     5     5     4     5
gene2      4      5     5     5     4     5     5     5     4     5
gene3      4      5     5     5     4     5     5     5     4     5
gene4      3      4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
gene5      4      5     5     5     4     5     5     5     4     5
gene6      4      5     5     5     4     5     5     5     4     5
gene7      4      5     5     5     4     5     5     5     4     5
gene8      3      4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
gene9      4      5     5     5     4     5     5     5     4     5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(gene = c("gene1", "gene10", "gene2", "gene3", 
"gene4", "gene5", "gene6", "gene7", "gene8", "gene9"), P1 = c(0.111, 
1.627, -1.766, -1.346, -0.783, 0.386, 0.547, 0.785, -0.186, -0.177
), P2 = c(0.319, 2.252, -0.056, 1.283, NA, -0.309, -0.144, -1.827, 
NA, 1.497), P3 = c(0.151, 1.462, -0.369, 0.322, -0.005, -0.886, 
-0.725, 0.986, 0.401, -1.37), P4 = c(NA, -1.339, 1.91, -0.465, 
1.761, -0.072, -0.133, 1.555, 0.9, -1.628), P5 = c(-0.397, -0.644, 
0.981, 0.403, 0.066, 0.161, 1.059, -0.798, -1.075, -1.044)), .Names = c("gene", 
"P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x022524a0>)
```

Comment: `tcrossprod(x)` is faster than `x%*%t(x)`

Comment: @Khashaa thank you for the suggestion, very good thing to know. I'll add this as another base option. I'd like to know if a data.table solution can be even faster.

Comment: How big is your `df`?

Comment: @Khashaa 25061 rows for 5862 columns (counting the one with the gene)

Comment: Expressing `calc_nonNA` as sparse matrix might be faster.

Comment: @Khashaa you can post an answer with this alternative, I'd love to also see benchmark with it

Comment: Been browsing over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244685/count-every-possible-pair-of-values-in-a-column-grouped-by-multiple-columns/26247144#26247144 and the answer linked therein, for inspiration. No luck so far:)

Comment: Does a "large df" mean more rows or more columns? If the columns stay the same and you just add rows, the problem is quite small, since there are only 2^5 possible values for each row and so `choose(2^5,2)`=496 pairs of rows to consider.

Comment: @Frank, the current df I'm working with is 25061 x 5862 (inlcuding the column with the names) but I can later have dfs with more rows and/or more columns. I'm also doing those calculations for df with same number of rows but less columns

Comment: Oh, oops, noticed you mentioned that in an earlier comment, too. Might want to put something regarding that into the question itself. I guess the frequency of NAs may also be relevant, `sum(calc_nonNA)/length(calc_nonNA)`. I'm curious to see what people find, but don't have any ideas myself.

Comment: @Frank ok for the edit. I don't like the far end of your comment ;-). Regarding NAs, it is pretty "random", some lines don't have any while some others have plenty of...

Comment: @CathG What is the proportion of NAs? Less than 10%?

Comment: @Khashaa I've got 39% of missing data

Comment: @CathG,  Alas, the sparse method is inferior with sparsity like that.

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670053/transposing-a-data-table) question's benchmarks it appears you're better off with matrix than DT.  Further, assuming you have or don't mind acquiring an Nvidia gpu that http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/gputools.pdf would be a good package for these types of problems.

Answer (score 4):

Using *dplyr*, transform data wide to long, then join to itself and summarise. Not sure if it is more efficient than your solution, some benchmarking anyone?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# reshaping from wide to long
x <- df %>% gather(key = P, value = value, -c(1)) %>% 
  mutate(value=(!is.na(value)))

# result
left_join(x,x,by="P") %>% 
  group_by(gene.x,gene.y) %>% 
  summarise(N=sum(value.x & value.y)) %>% 
  spread(gene.y,N)
```

**EDIT:**
Shame, this *dplyr* solution fails for bigger dataset 2600x600, can't join to itself - `internal vecseq reached physical limit`, about 2^31 rows...

By the way, here is benchmark for `t` vs `tcrossprod`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

op <- microbenchmark(
  BASE_t={
    calc_nonNA <- !is.na(df[, -1, with=F])
    calc_nonNA %*% t(calc_nonNA)
    },
  BASE_tcrossprod={
    calc_nonNA <- !is.na(df[, -1, with=F])
    tcrossprod(calc_nonNA)
  },
  times=10
  )

qplot(y=time, data=op, colour=expr) + scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for then benchmark, so, definitely I'm at least switching or tcrossprod!

Answer (score 3):

I tried this out with random data of 25061x5862 and it quickly chewed up 50gb of ram (including swap space) and, as such, is way way way less memory efficient than using `tcrossprod` but if you have an obscene amount of memory then *maybe* (but probably not) this could be faster.

```
#generate cross columns for all matches
crossDT<-data.table(gene=rep(df1[,unique(gene)],length(df1[,unique(gene)])),gene2=rep(df1[,unique(gene)],each=length(df1[,unique(gene)])))
#create datatable with row for each combo
df2<-merge(df1,crossDT,by="gene")
setkey(df2,gene2)
setkey(df1,gene)
#make datatable with a set of P columns for each gene
df3<-df1[df2]
#find middle column and then make name vectors
pivotcol<-match("i.gene",names(df3))
names1<-names(df3)[2:(pivotcol-1)]
names2<-names(df3)[(pivotcol+1):ncol(df3)]
names3<-paste0("new",names1)
#make third set of P columns where the new value is False if either of the previous sets of P columns is NA
df3[,(names3):=lapply(1:length(names1),function(x) !any(is.na(c(get(names1[x]),get(names2[x]))))),by=c("gene","i.gene")]
#delete first sets of P columns
df3[,c(names1,names2):=NULL]
#sum up true columns
df3[,Sum:=rowSums(.SD),.SDcols=names3]
#delete set of P columns
df3[,(names3):=NULL]
#cast results to desired shape
dcast.data.table(df3,gene~i.gene,value.var='Sum')
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I confirm that I do not have that amount of RAM though (more like 12Gb ;-)) but this is nonetheless interesting. And thanks for the link on the other question.